# Best way to deploy VB.NET Code / create an assembly on a SQLServer

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2005

I've created some functions / procedures with VB.NET and want to deploy them to a SQLServer. Within Visual Studio you can click right and select "deploy". An assembly will be created on the server and a lot of functions and  procedures. It's really easy.

Now I want to script the whole deployment process. What is Visual Studio doing when I make a deployment? Can Visual Studio autoscript all the deployment steps for me? Can I save it to a file and execute it manually?

Answer (score 0):

Look into MSBuild, this runs a script generated by VS i believe. sorry i cant provide more information that this but it might give you that extra "hint" required to find what you need.